# Java input readers - chaining the input stream API

Tags: java, url, streaming, urlconnection

what the difference between both stream chaining methods ?

first :

```
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(someUrlConnection.getInputStream(), encoding));
```

second :

```
            InputStream raw = someUrlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(raw);
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(buffer);
```